# Using AlchemyAPI to analyze sentiment for each tweet.

Tags: json, sentiment-analysis, alchemyapi

We would like to use Alchemy API to get the sentiment analysis data for each tweet. The use case is that if we submit a set of JSON docs (which are tweet objects) as input to Alchemy Sentiment Analysis API, can we get a sentiment analysis score for each of the JSON doc. As we checked, we are always getting the Overall Sentiment Analysis score.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the sentiment for a single tweet, you need to submit each tweet as a single document. Document level sentiment will analyze the sentiment of all the tweets in the doc and give you an overall sentiment.

You might also want to extract entities, keywords and concepts and get the sentiment for each. You can also try targeting a specific entity or phrase and get the sentiment with user targeted sentiment. http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/sentiment/urls.html#targetedsentiment